# Parsing winerror.h & ntstatus.h statuses/definitions with regex

Tags: python, c, regex, windows, header

I'm trying to create a regex in Python to capture all the Last Errors, HRESULT and NTSTATUS defenitions from winerror.h & ntstatus.h:

- http://www.carrona.org/winerror.html
- http://www.codemachine.com/downloads/win71/ntstatus.h

For example, for this text:

```
//
// MessageId: NTE_BAD_PROV_TYPE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Invalid provider type specified.
// More data is avaiable on bla bla.
//
#define NTE_BAD_PROV_TYPE                _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80090014L)
```

I want to capture:

`('Invalid provider type specified. More data is avaiable on bla bla.', 
 'NTE_BAD_PROV_TYPE',
  0x80090014)`

---

Same goes for `ntstatus.h`:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED
//
// MessageText:
//
// Indicates not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.
// This allows, for example, all privileges to be disabled without having to know exactly which privileges are assigned.
//
#define STATUS_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED          ((NTSTATUS)0x00000106L)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the regex I ended up figuring out and using:**

To capture all Last Errors & HRESULT definitions in `winerror.h`:

```
//\sMessageText:[\n\r]+//\s*[\n\r]+
(?P<message_text>//.*?//\n)*.*?
#define\s(?P<status_name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)
\s+(?:_HRESULT_TYPEDEF_\(|NDIS_ERROR_TYPEDEF_\()?
(?P<status_value>(?:0[xX])?[A-Fa-f0-9]+)L
```

To capture all NTSTATUS definitions in `ntstatus.h`:

```
//\sMessageText:[\n\r]+//\s*[\n\r]+
(?P<message_text>//.*?//\n)*.*?
#define\s(?P<status_name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)
\s+\(\(NTSTATUS\)(?P<status_value>0[xX]?[A-Fa-f0-9]+)L\)
```

I also format the description (message text) afterwards by replacing the `//` with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close enough:

`re.findall(r"(?<=// )(?:Message\w{2,4}:)? ?(.+)?\n", text)` **+** `list(re.search(r"(0x\d+)", text).groups())`

`['NTE_BAD_PROV_TYPE',
  '',
  'Invalid provider type specified.',
  'More data is avaiable on bla bla.',
  '0x80090014']`